# Can I lay new ceramic tile over old linoleum tile?

Tags: tile

I want to re-tile my laundry room. The existing linoleum tile is glued directly to the concrete slab with some sort of black adhesive.

I don't want to pull up the old tile. If I put down backerboard and lay ceramic penny tile over it, will I have problems with the new tile cracking?

Additional Info: The original linoleum tile is asbestos and that's why I don't want to pull it up unless it's absolutely necessary.